# Beginning rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been doing desktop applications since I have started programming, and I have not really looked at the web side of things. Seeing how fast this market is growing, I convinced myself that I should learn a web framework. I learned some PHP, and I found it to be quick, but, after projects get beyond small, it becomes a hassle.

So, looking at recommendations online, I took up Ruby on Rails. Now, when I go through the ruby on rails guide, I don't really feel like I'm understanding anything, or really writing any code. I just feel like I'm editing configuration files. Is this normal? Should I just keep going through the guide, and it will all come to me later?

FYI, I'm using [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) as a tutorial.

When I coded in PHP, I immediately understood what the code was doing, but, with Rails, I really don't understand how all of it comes together.

EDIT: I am good at Python and C, and not bad at Java, if that changes your answer.

Comment: My way was just reading my first book, following all the instruction without many thoughts... and when it was finished I realized, that it makes sense. All this associations, MVC, scopes and other new stuff for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you start on Rails, I would start with the pick axe book (Programming Ruby
by Dave Thomas http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9) since you have previous programming exprience and make sure you have a solid grounding in Ruby.
Then I would go through the Ruby Koans and do some of the ruby quiz's.  Both are fun and great practice.

Then I would start with either Michael Hartl's http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book or Agile Web Development with Rails (http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) make sure you are getting the latest edition.

I would suggest Michael Hartl's tutorial first.  Don't worry if you feel led by the nose a bit. I found Agile Web Development with Rails, as with a lot of the PragProg books, to expect me to go out and do a lot of research on my own along the way, like in the guides, because the topic is so big.

Then, if you don't know Javascript, you are going to want get a solid grounding in that as well.  The Crockford book is highly recommended, but i found that I had to go through something basic first before I could understand a lot of the points that Crockford was making.

Just remember, despite the fact that everybody talks about how powerful/beautiful Ruby is (it is!) and how wonderful rails is (it is!), normal developers aren't going to tell you that it is easy to learn, at least, not the ones that understand the complexity and depth of both.  With both you have to work pretty hard to understand them.  With Rails, it takes a while to remember all the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try other tutorial, for example this one http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

In this tutorial, author shows how to build a real app, IMO this is the best way to learn a new technology, by practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not normal - it's nice!

With Ruby on Rails we stick to a convention over configuration principle. 
You should understand rails conventions. With that principle you can get a working site in 15 minutes without any configuration or coding based on best practices.
If you need something special you can code it by your own.

Small advice: buy a book. It is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend this online tutorial - "Rails for zombies" -> http://railsforzombies.org/

I have walked through this tutorial and I know two other friends that have started with Ruby on Rails using this site. It is really fun and easy to begin coding.